# Parent item height not solved by clearfix

Tags: html, css, height, clearfix

Can't figure out why my div.partner-item will not take the height of it's child elements.  Check out my fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/edjcqkke/2/.  If you inspect the 'partner-item' div you can see that it does not have the height of its children elements.  I have cleared my floats but still can't get the parent height to recognize its children's height. My html structure:

```
<div id="partner-container" class="standard small container">
  <div class="partner-item">
    <div class="flipper">
      <div class="front">
        <img class="logo" src="http://fillmurray.com/300/150">
        <h2>Test Page</h2>
        <p>www.googlre.vi9m</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="partner-item">
    <div class="flipper">
      <div class="front">
        <img class="logo" src="http://fillmurray.com/300/150">
        <h2>new-item</h2>
        <p>http://www.google.com</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="partner-item">
    <div class="flipper">
      <div class="front">
        <img class="logo" src="http://fillmurray.com/300/150"><h2>partner-item</h2><p>undefined</p>  
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

Comment: Clearfix is for floated elements , here you have absolute positioned elements inside `partner-item` so the `height` is `0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<div class="front">` has `position: absolute` property. So it doesn't take any space from the parent element. That's why `<div class="flipper">` doesn't recognize it's child's height.